# VHDL process parallelism

Tags: vhdl

let's say I have two processes in my code:

```
prc 1 :  process( CLK , RESETN ) {with some code}
Q <= outd
prc2 : process(outd,RESETN)
```

Note that we change outd in prc1..

A process is executed in parallel with other processes, right? how can it be executed in parallel if we dont change it's sensitivity list? in my code.. how can prc2 be executed in parallel with process 1 If I didnt change the sensitivity list of it?

And another question.. is the line `Q <= outd` placement has importance? doest it change anything If I put it in the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description has taken from [http://www.vhdl.renerta.com](http://www.vhdl.renerta.com/source/vhd00062.htm):

> The sensitivity list is a compact way of specifying the set of signals, events on which may resume a process. A sensitivity list is specified right after the keyword **process**
>   The sensitivity list is equivalent to the **wait on** statement, which is the last statement of the process statement section

So your `prc2` process will wait for changing of `outd` or `RESETN` and then will start to work as many times as signals in sensitivity list will changed.

Parallelism means that all process executed in parallel. One process doesn't wait for the end of another process, but works in parallel with it. In your case: the process `prc1` will work each `CLK` or `RESETN` changing and the process `prc2` will work when `outd` or `RESETN` changing.

To see the picture how it works you can write (or take any example) some module and testbench for it and look at waveform how processes work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Roman's answer, I thought I'd answer your second question:

> Is the placement of the line `Q <= outd` important? Does it change anything if I put it in the last line?

No and no.

As long as the line `Q <= outd` is not inside of a process, it is purely combinational. Thus, it doesn't matter where you put it in the code - it will be synthesized into the same hardware.